# How to pass data to view returned by the route redirected to (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

**The following is my situation.**

I have two models with controllers containing CRUD methods.

- Document.
- File.

While creating a file, an already document is to be specified (selected) to which the created file will be attached to.

In the `store` method of my `documentController` after storing the newly created document I want to redirect to `files/create` route with the `id` of newly created document, so that files can be created without having to choose a document.

**What I have so far**

*DocumentController*

```
 $input = $request->all();
 $document = $this->documentRepository->create($input);
 return redirect(route('files.create'),array('documentID' => $document->id));
```

*file/create.blade.php*

```
@if( isset($documentID) )
<input type="text" name="document_id" value="{{ $documentID }}" hidden="true">

@else
<div class="form-group col-sm-6">

    {!! Form::label('file_type', 'Document ID:') !!}

    <select name="document_id" class="form-control">
        @foreach( $documents as $document)
            <option value="{{ $document->id }}">{{ $document->id }}-{{ $document->applicant()->name }}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>
@endif
```

How can i achive this.

Comment: What issue are you facing exactly, are you not able to retrieve $document->id

Comment: Rahul, i am getting following error when trying to pass $documentID to the redirect -  `InvalidArgumentException in Response.php line 458:
The HTTP status code "1" is not valid.`

Comment: @PrakharSingh, You're receiving that error because the rediect() method is casting the `array('documentID' => $document->id)` you are passing as the second parameter to an integer, which is 1, and then trying to return a response with a HTTP status code of 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second parameter in the response() method is the http status code that should be used when redirecting.

You need to chain the with() method:

```
 $input = $request->all();
 $document = $this->documentRepository->create($input);
 return redirect(route('files.create'))->with('documentID', $document->id);
```

You can then access the passed session data from the view with `{{ session('documentID') }}`

See: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/responses#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data

Comment: This is the only correct answer here at the moment.

Comment: Alexey is right, but i can't understand why `isset( $_SESSION['documentID']) ` is returning false while i can easily print its value.

Comment: @PrakharSingh, Use `if (session('documentID'))` instead. :)

Comment: Undefined index: documentID :(

Comment: @PrakharSingh, You'll have to put the relevant code (both controllers and view) somewhere I can view it for me to help further.

Comment: Thanks @ktross, I figured it out

Answer (score 1):

a way to solve this is to make new route that accepts `documentID` so you'll get something like `Route::get('/files/createFromDocument/{$documentID}', 'FileController@createFromDocument')->name('files.createFromDocument');`

in `FileController` you've to add the new function 

`function createFromDocument($documentID)`

and here you can handle this special case

Comment: Thanks, Elwan, that's the last option I have. I was thinking if there is a batter way.

Comment: in some cases separating functionalities is the best practice. but if there's no code difference

Comment: some cases separating functionalities is the best practice. but if there's no code difference I think @ktross solution is best match.

Answer (score 0):

Edited: Try this code

```
return redirect()->route('files.create', ['documentID' => $document->id]);
```

Comment: Thanks, Rahul I know I can always return `view`. but I actually want to load the `view` from my `fileController` because I am including other variables there as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
return redirect()->route('files.create', $document->id);
```

Comment: Doan, how should i access the passed variable?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
return redirect("files/$document->id/create")
```

Route:

```
Route::get('/files/{$documentID}/create', 'FileController@createDocument');
```

Function :

```
public function createDocument($documentId){}
```